# Text View comes second line if the space is available

Tags: android, textview

In my application, I have one text view, the text view length is 30, if the device space not enough then it will go to the next line. But in my case, if the space available also, it goes to the next line. In XML, it is showing well.

[image]

but when I run the real device, the text comes to the second and third lines also, but space is the available right side.

[image]

This is the text view I am using

```
 <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <TextView
          android:textSize="@dimen/normal_font_size_newuser_final"
          android:text="@string/useridset"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
          <TextView
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_font_size_newuser_final"
            android:id="@+id/userid_new_final"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="venkataramanajagu1234567890_12 is setup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Here how to utilize the right side space.So please guide me on how to achieve this, Any properties for text view

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score -1):

Try changing as below:

```
<LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Also try changing layout_width to "match parent" for TextViews